# Find Maximum month from two slicers

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have this data in a pbix file:

```
ImaginaryData = 
DATATABLE (
    "Month", DATETIME, 
    "Amount", INTEGER, 
    { 
        { "01 JAN 2018", 10 }, 
        { "01 FEB 2018", 15 }, 
        { "01 MAR 2018", 25 }, 
        { "01 APR 2018", 60 }, 
        { "01 MAY 2018", 55 }
    }
```

On the canvas we have two Date field slicers:

[image]

How do I create two measures?:

- Max Month Selected
- Min Month Selected

I tried this for Max Month Selected but it does not work:

```
Max Month Selected = 
    Calculate(
        MAX(ImaginaryData[Month]),
        ImaginaryData
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When two or more slicers filter the same column, you will always get the **intersection** of values - not the union. So in other words, if you select one value in the first slicer, and a different value in the second slicer, you would basically end up with a blank filter. That can also be seen if you drag the [Amount] column into your report:

[image]

Instead, you should use a single slicer and allowing the user to select a range of months, for example using the "Between" option:

[image]

Then, the following measures should work as expected:

```
Max Month Selected = MAX(ImaginaryData[Month])
Min Month Selected = MIN(ImaginaryData[Month])
```

If you must have two dropdown slicers, the only workaround is to create two tables, both containing the [Month] column, and have one slicer pointing to one table, and the other slicer pointing to the second table. Then, you would define your measures as:

```
Max Month Selected = MAX(MAX('MonthTable1'[Month]), MAX('MonthTable2'[Month]))
Min Month Selected = MIN(MIN('MonthTable1'[Month]), MIN('MonthTable2'[Month]))
```